# cordova-plugin-file missing command error on uwp

Tags: cordova, uwp, cordova-plugin-file

I am trying to make an application with Cordova that must work with Widows 10 (UWP). But when I use the cordova-plugin-file, I get an error "missing command error". After a quick research I found out that this error appears when plugin is not installed or when platform is not supported by the platform. But when I look in the doc and the code, the plugin is well installed and it does support Windows 10.

I tried downgrade plugin to 5.0.0 instead of 6.0.1, I tried remove and readd platform Windows, I tried uninstall and reintall plugin.

```
    this.file.getFreeDiskSpace().then(freeDiskSpace => {
      return freeDiskSpace * 1000;
    });
```

Comment: Could you please provide detailed error log?

Comment: I would like to, unforunately the only error log I get is "missing command error" :/

Comment: Please  set `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run-> MSBuild project build output verbosity/log file verbosity` to "detailed/diagnostic" and check the detailed log from build log window not output window.

Comment: I don't launch the windows app through Visual Studio because it can't build if the project is on an external server disk. Is there a way to get these logs with cordova cli ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Could you please try copy the project to local and build it.

Comment: I get more logs, it says it cannot find file "ms-appx-web://[appname]/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/src/windows/FileTransferProxy.js". I tried to copy this file in platforms/windows/plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer, but now it says "ms-appx-web://[appname]/www/assets/jsPlugins/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js
0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected"

Comment: That error comes from  `PdfJS` lib in your app. You should try to debug it and see whether you are using it wrongly in your app.